# Pycharm unable to debug the Python Flask project

Tags: python, flask, debugging, pycharm

I have a simple Flask based project in Pycharm. I am trying to debug this by right clicking and selecting debug option. But keeps getting below error:

```
Connected to pydev debugger (build 232.9559.58)
 * Serving Flask app 'app'
 * Debug mode: on
WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment. Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Running on all addresses (0.0.0.0)
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:8000
 * Running on http://192.168.0.29:8000
Press CTRL+C to quit
 * Restarting with stat
C:\Python311\python.exe: can't open file 'C:\\Program': [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Process finished with exit code 2
```

I am unable to understand why and what it is looking for in `'C:\\Program'`. I am able to run the file perfectly fine and only having issues in debug. What can I try next?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This appears to be a bug in Pycharm. Multiple issues have been raised for the same in the JetBrains bug tracker.

- [FLASK_DEBUG=1 breaks debugger when Python/PyCharm installation path
  has spaces](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-60819/FLASKDEBUG1-breaks-debugger-when-Python-PyCharm-installation-path-has-spaces)
- [Flask Debug session cannot be started in PyCharm](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-61402/Flask-Debug-session-cannot-be-started-in-PyCharm)
- [Flask debugger is not working on Windows because of white space in installation directory if application is specified](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-62459/Flask-debugger-is-not-working-on-Windows-because-of-white-space-in-installation-directory-if-application-is-specified)
- [flask server run failed because of space character in file path](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-62441/flask-server-run-failed-because-of-space-character-in-file-path)
- [Can not run flask project in debug mod](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-60825/Can-not-run-flask-project-in-debug-mod)

You can follow [this](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-60819/FLASKDEBUG1-breaks-debugger-when-Python-PyCharm-installation-path-has-spaces#focus=Comments-27-8071749.0-0) comment(or [this](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-62459/Flask-debugger-is-not-working-on-Windows-because-of-white-space-in-installation-directory-if-application-is-specified#focus=Comments-27-8002622.0-0) comment) to get a temporary workaround.